# clearInterval to stop hover animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I have the below [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/fJqKV/21/)

When I hover over prev I want it to move as it is doing and when I stop hovering I want it to stop.
See the code below. The alert works when I stop hovering but the clearInterval does not?
What am I doing wrong here?

```
    <div> <span id="prev">prev</span>

        <div class="scroll-container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f33636/fff">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c5b9e/fff">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0c9e0c/fff">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    var hoverInterval;
    function goLeft() {
        if (!$('.img-container').is(':animated')) {
            var first = $('.img-container img:first-child');
            var firstClone = first.clone();
            $('.img-container').append(firstClone);
            $('.img-container').animate({
                "left": "-=110px"
            }, "slow", function () {
                first.remove();
                $('.img-container').css("left", "0");
            });
        }
    }
    $('#prev').hover(

    function () {
        hoverInterval = setInterval(goLeft, 100);
    },
    function () {
        alert(1);
        clearInterval(goLeft);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
clearInterval(hoverInterval);
```